Ensuring integer or array of integers with express-validator
I'm puzzled with a validator while trying express.
An optional parameter I receive to my route, flags, should either be an integer or an array of integers.
The array of integers part is checked with the help of a custom validator chained after isArray().
Below is my validating code, and examples of data it lets in.

                oneOf([
                    body("flags").isInt(),
                    body("flags")
                        .optional()
                        .isArray()
                        .custom((value) => {
                            //return value.every(Number.isInteger);
                            if (!value.every(Number.isInteger)) {
                                throw new Error('permissionFlags should contain Integers only');
                            }
                            return true;
                        }),
                ], {
                    message: 'it should be an integer or an array of integers',
                }),

All the following sorts of values are being let in, however the first one isn't an array of integers.
flags: [ 8, 1, 'WRONG_PERMISSION' ] // this is not an int, neither an array of integers.

flags: [ 8, 1 ]

flags: 8
flags: ['WRONG_PERMISSION', 8, 1 ] // however, this wrong array is blocked.

A big thank in advance for a good advice.

Well, the problem was fixed in a more recent version of express-validator.
I recommend myself, and anybody else, to upgrade with npm i express-validator@7 .
good luck
